# Include raw JSX text of source file in a Gatsby page/component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm working on a Gatsby site that has documentation for a React component. I have several example components that show example usage of the component. The example components serve as live examples, but I'd also like to show the code of the example. Currently, I'm just copying the source code and pasting it into a `code` block in the documentation page, but this feels like duplicated effort.

Is there a way I could have Gatsby read the source file's content, and insert that into a `code` block so I don't have to keep the example source in the page in sync with the actual source?

I've tried using the `raw-loader` to do this. It almost works, but it includes the compiled JavaScript, so the JSX syntax is gone. Is there an option I can use with the `raw-loader` perhaps to accomplish what I need here?

Comment: you could try [gatsby-mdx](https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-mdx) or [docz](https://www.docz.site/)

Comment: Ya, I think `raw-loader` might be the way to go unless you want to start using `mdx` like @BoyWithSilverWings suggested. I know that spectacle-code-slide (https://github.com/jamiebuilds/spectacle-code-slide) uses `raw-loader` to load code for the purposes of presentation slides.

Comment: @RobertCooper I was on the right track with `raw-loader`. I checked the docs, and it turns out I need to prefix `raw-loader` with two exclamation points, e.g. ``!!raw-loader!./MyFile.js` so that it skips the other loaders associated with that file. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Ah, interesting! Glad you figured it out